# Flowchart in question and answer

Tags: feature-request

I would like to ask for a feature if it is possible to add Flowchart facility in the question and answer block. this would be very useful because flowchart can help explain the **algorithm** better. most of the code samples are not compile able but are given for the demonstration purpose. a flowchart will do a better job at that I believe.

Of course a diagram can be copy pasted but editing it will be difficult. moreover if there is flowchart facility and if there is an error in the flowchart not only the author can edit it but also others can edit it in-place. editing this flowchart also will be as quick as the code edit.

[related question without ans ans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138998/ability-to-draw-and-add-graphical-illustrations-flowcharts-diagrams-etc)
thanks.