# Upload an image by pasting in Firefox

Tags: feature-request, images, firefox

I don't know how, but there's a [site that can let you paste images without any obvious flash/java crap](http://pasteboard.co/). I don't have to explain how incredibly handy that would be.

Unfortunately, Stack Exchange is unable to get the images from that site, not even by direct URL, so I have to create a file like an idiot every time.

It appears like this is just due to Stack Exchange [not supporting pasting images to upload on Firefox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232417/has-pasting-images-directly-into-the-upload-box-been-dropped-or-is-it-just-me/233874#comment768859_233874), could this feature please be added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It now works for me in firefox without any problems.

Answer (score 8):

The image uploader already supports pasting an image, in [browsers that support it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233874).

Just copy the image, open the image upload dialog box in the Stack Exchange editor, and paste. It's all done in JavaScript withthe [DataTransfer interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-datatransfer-interface).

Also see the [original feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120943/add-an-image-directly-from-the-clipboard) (marked completed).

Comment: So let's sum it. The application I linked to works for me. Here, the pasting doesn't work for me. Am I really the one who's wrong? I have seen the original request but since it's marked complete and is incomplete, I deemed it irelevant.

Comment: @TomášZato: I don't know. What browser do you use? Also see [Pasting images from clipboard with Chrome](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255854) where the developer explains that he had to go through some considerable amount of pain to keep things working for Webkit, and that other browsers may not be supported at the moment.

Comment: I use firefox, just like the 1st commentator in the answer you linked to. They told him it does never work - I'm pointing out that [it does](https://github.com/JoelBesada/pasteboard).

Comment: @TomášZato: what Oded means is that it has never worked *in the Stack Exchange widget*. He did not mean to say that it cannot be done, just that it was never done *here*.

Comment: Ahh well. So is the request completed or is it not? In which browsers it actually works? In IE?

Comment: @TomášZato: Chrome and Safari (== Webkit-based browsers, although Chrome has forked away since).