# Remote parser fails to parse image in my post but javascript parser (during edit) parses it OK

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

[This is the post.](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/34701/can-i-edit-sound-as-fourier-transformations) Please don't edit it until I get some answer here. It might be my fault but it might also be a bug.

This is the code I see:

It looks like this:

```
![all guitar strings as seen by FFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeTSw.png)
<sup>All strings on my guitar. Produced using [this program I made in hope to create nice pure javasript guitar tuner][2]. [Relevant question][3].</sup>

Some description:

![image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQMdD.png)
```

This is the preview I see:

[image: image description]

But this is the post as seen by everyone:

[image: image description]

And this is the HTML:

```
<p><img alt="all guitar strings as seen by FFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeTSw.png)
&lt;sup&gt;All strings on my guitar. Produced using [this program I made in hope to create nice pure javasript guitar tuner" src="http://u8.8u.cz/tuner/">. <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/q/23807783/607407">Relevant question</a>.</p>
```

Maybe the remote parser is too greedy?

Comment: "Please don't edit it until I get some answer here." -- Having your question look correctly is much more important (and the broken post is still available in the [revision list](http://sound.stackexchange.com/posts/34701/revisions)).

Comment: @balpha Ok, thanks for fixing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Maybe the remote parser is too greedy?

Sort of, yeah. The server-side version ran the offending regular expressions in single-line mode, the client-side didn't*, which can in very rare cases cause this discrepancy (in fact you may have been the very first one to ever trigger this). From the next build on, they'll both behave identically.

A second issue that contributed to the problem is mixing inline `[...](...)` and reference-style `[...][...]` links and images, which can be problematic sometimes (though in this particular case, it no longer will be). More importantly though, they should be equally problematic in both Markdown versions.

<sub>Yes, JavaScript regex don't even *have* a single-line mode. It can be easily simulated, however.</sub>

Comment: I use the inline images because I have a tool to paste images directly into text-area. And [I didn't find a convenient api to add a refference-style link](http://stackapps.com/q/4997/28478). Also I didn't feel like re-implementing it manually.

Comment: That's absolutely okay, I didn't mean to criticize you for it. BTW, we natively support pasting images (Ctrl-G Ctrl-V).

Comment: No, we don't. And when I pointed that out, [I got downvoted to oblivion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242275/209994). That's why I implemented my method. Also the upload form blocks writing for the duration of upload. On slow connections, this can get annoying.